# Shell script is not working on Oozie using Hue

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, hue

I am running Shell script on Oozie using Hue, when the workflow job is submitted the following error is shown:

```
Cannot run program "FileManipulation.sh" 
(in directory "/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/root/jobcache/job_201503271756_0277/attempt_201503271756_0277_m_000000_0/work"): 
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Is FileManipulation.sh added a 'File' in the workflow?

Comment: could you share the workflow

Comment: What's "Oozie", "Hue"?   Do you have the where-with-all to examine the directory to see if there is a file there?   Do you know the circumstances under which there should be a file there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check directory permission containing `FileManipulation.sh` file. Give all `read`, `write` and `execute` permissions to directory and its file. Also add path to the shell script in both "Shell command" as well as "Files", sometimes this may cause same problem.